# Group by transformed column

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have a database with creations and orders, and a bunch of tables linking them.

I want to extract, for each month, the number of ordered creations, and the sum of amount for these orders, but for a specific creation name pattern, and a specific type of product references.

I have this, which doesn't work because the inner query does not knows the `yearcrea` and `monthcrea` columns:

```
select
date_part('year', c.created_at) as yearcrea,
date_part('month', c.created_at) as monthcrea,
p.reference,
count (*) as nb,
(
  select sum(o2.amount_ati_cents)
  from creations as c2
  inner join products as p on c.product_id = p.id
  inner join order_items as oi2 on c2.id = oi2.creation_id
  inner join bundles as b2 on b2.id = oi2.bundle_id
  inner join orders as o2 on o2.id = b2.order_id
  where o2.status NOT IN ('canceled', 'new')
  and c2.name like '% - Premium(%'
  and p2.reference like 'FLA_%'
  and date_part('year', c2.created_at) = yearcrea
  and date_part('month', c2.created_at) = monthcrea
) as ca

from creations as c
inner join products as p on c.product_id = p.id

where c.name like '% - Premium(%'
and p.reference like 'FLA_%'

and c.id in (
    select oi.creation_id
    from order_items as oi
    inner join bundles as b on b.id = oi.bundle_id
    inner join orders as o on o.id = b.order_id
    where o.status NOT IN ('canceled', 'new')
)

group by yearcrea, monthcrea, reference
order by yearcrea desc, monthcrea desc
```

I have also tried

```
and date_part('year', c2.created_at) = date_part('year', c.created_at)
and date_part('month', c2.created_at) = date_part('month', c.created_at)
```

but I get an error: `subquery uses ungrouped column "c.created_at" from outer query`.

How can I filter a select sub-query with "transformed" columns ?

Maybe I'm looking at it the wrong way and there is a simpler way to extract the info I want ?

Comment: I removed the `[plpgsql]` tag. This simple SQL, no need for the plpgsql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Lennart, with the usage of `count(distinct c.id)`, I can successfully both count the creations and the sum of amount:

```
select
date_part('year', c.created_at) as yearcrea,
date_part('month', c.created_at) as monthcrea,
p.reference,
count (distinct c.id) as nb_crea,
(sum(o.amount_ati_cents) / 100) as ca_euros

from creations as c
inner join products as p on c.product_id = p.id
inner join order_items as oi on oi.creation_id = c.id
inner join bundles as b on b.id = oi.bundle_id
inner join orders as o on o.id = b.order_id

where o.status NOT IN ('canceled', 'new')
and c.name like '% - Premium(%'
and p.reference like 'FLA_%'

group by yearcrea, monthcrea, reference
order by yearcrea desc, monthcrea desc
```

Comment: Cosmo0, you should mark your answer as a solution

Comment: Yep, I had to wait 2 days. Now I can :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify further:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', c.created_at) AS year_month
     , p.reference,
     , count (distinct c.id) as nb_crea,
     , (sum(o.amount_ati_cents) / 100) as ca_euros
from   creations   c
join   products    p on p.id = c.product_id 
join   order_items i on i.creation_id = c.id
join   bundles     b on b.id = i.bundle_id
join   orders      o on o.id = b.order_id
where  o.status NOT IN ('canceled', 'new')
and    c.name like '% - Premium(%'
and    p.reference like 'FLA_%'
GROUP BY year_month, reference
ORDER BY year_month DESC;
```

Or even:

```
SELECT to_char(c.created_at, 'YYYY-MM') AS year_month
...
GROUP  BY 1, reference
ORDER  BY 1 DESC;
```

[`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) and [to_char()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-formatting.html) in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

yearcrea and monthcrea does not exists at the time when the sub-select is evaluated. The following should work:

```
and date_part('year', c2.created_at) = date_part('year', c.created_at)
and date_part('month', c2.created_at) = date_part('month', c.created_at)
```

but do you really need creations as c2 and products as p2 in the sub-select? Should not:

```
(
    select sum(o2.amount_ati_cents)
    from order_items as oi2 
    join bundles as b2 
        on b2.id = oi2.bundle_id
    join orders as o2 
        on o2.id = b2.order_id
    where o2.status NOT IN ('canceled', 'new')
      and c.id = oi2.creation_id
) as ca
```

be sufficient?

Without investigating it more closely, it looks as you could transform the sub-selects in the in clause and  the sum to a join at the outer level.

Comment: With the first suggestion (which I tried but forgot to mention), I get `subquery uses ungrouped column "c.created_at" from outer query`. Yes I need to make sure that the products.reference is also 'FLA_' and that the creations.name contains ' - Premium(' (which I forgot). Thanks for your help :)

Comment: For the transformation from sub-selects to sum and join, I'm trying to, but I get too many rows in the count(*) because a creation can be in multiple bundles, but I want to count the creations.

Comment: Does count(distinct...) help?

Comment: @cosmo0, for the first suggestion, you should also use `group by date_part('year', c.created_at), date_part('month', c.created_at), p.reference`. Using the column aliases (defined in `select`) in the `group by` is not good practise anyway (and not allowed by most DBMS).

Comment: @Lennart: I don't have a working query without sub-queries yet, but I'll try it. @ypercude: I grouped by `date_part()` in both the sub-query and the main query but no change.

Comment: @Lennard: `count(distinct)` does help! I'll post an answer with my result. Thanks !